# Ajax - create folder

Tags: php, ajax

i am using the following `php` code to create a folder and a sub folder on `xampp` server...

```
<?php  
$userFolder = "poop";
mkdir($userFolder); 
$newfolder = $userFolder . "/bla bla bla"; 
mkdir($newfolder, 0777); 
// check to see if it has been created or not using is_dir 
if (is_dir($newfolder)) { 
    echo "The $newfolder directory has been created<br /><br />";     
}  

?>
```

my question is how do i use ajax to do this..... any help would be appreciated... :) thanks in advance... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the jQuery library (using it for brevity here), simply:

```
$.ajax({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'path/to/your/php/file.php',
  data: {folderName: 'someFolderName'},
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data); //"The directory has been created."
  } 
});
```

and in your php:

```
$userFolder = $_POST['folderName'];
```

jQuery isn't necessary for this. It's just less code to write. For plain javascript, [see here (click)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery).

Comment: i have used the following code

`<html>
<head>
<script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.wallform.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<script>
$("#button").click(function() {

$.ajax({
 
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'create.php',
  data: {folderName: 'someFolderName'},
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data); //"The directory has been created."
  } 
});  
   
});

</script>



<button id="button" onClick="xxx()">Create</button>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: and the php code

`<?php  
$userFolder = $_POST['folderName'];
mkdir($userFolder); 
$newfolder = $userFolder . "/bla bla bla"; 
mkdir($newfolder, 0777); // Make new folder and set file permissions on it ( chmod )
// check to see if it has been created or not using is_dir 
if (is_dir($newfolder)) { 
    echo "The $newfolder directory has been created<br /><br />";     
}  

?>`

Comment: @SRCSRC ...so, why did you feel the need to post all of this?

Comment: I solved your problem. I'm confused about why you made your own post using my solution rather than accepting my answer. @SRCSRC

Comment: @SRCSRC it's fine. I didn't mean you had to accept my answer, but I appreciate it. I just mean that your posted answer is redundant and poorly formatted.

Comment: well i should have accepted ur answer.... but well i was too high to think anything straight....

Answer (score 1):

assuming your file is dir.php

```
<?php  
$userFolder = "poop";
mkdir($userFolder); 
$newfolder = $userFolder . "/bla bla bla"; 
mkdir($newfolder, 0777); 
// check to see if it has been created or not using is_dir 
if (is_dir($newfolder)) { 
    echo "The $newfolder directory has been created<br /><br />";     
}  

?>
```

you can use jquery to call it

```
$.ajax({
  url: "dir.php",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() {
  //sucesss response here
});
```